# How to extract information out of multi-line string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
1970/11/05 18:40:06
Transferred:      484844 Bytes (4745455 Bytes/s)
Errors:                46
Checks:              5550
Transferred:         5450
Elapsed time:        8.6s
```

I want to extract all information (except for the data) out of string and save as an object. The problem with regex is the indent of the value, because the spaces between label and the value get smaller if the value gets bigger.
Any way to do that with Regex?

Comment: The answer is "yes" but my counter question is: why do this with regex?

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't use a regex, but a simple `split()` and `map()`. I parsed the data to a Map which I find very nice to use for stuff like that, though you could also use an object...

```
var str =  `1970/11/05 18:40:06
Transferred:      484844 Bytes (4745455 Bytes/s)
Errors:                46
Checks:              5550
Transferred:         5450
Elapsed time:        8.6s`;

var splitted = str.split("\n");
splitted.shift();

var data = new Map(splitted.map(v => {
    var f = v.replace(/\s/gm, "").split(":");
    return [f[0], f[1]]
}));

console.log(data.get("Errors")); // 46
```

If you prefer the solution to parse it to an object:

```
var obj = {};

splitted.forEach(function(v) {
    var f = v.replace(/\s/gm, "").split(":");
    obj[f[0]] = f[1]; 
});

console.log(obj.Errors)
```

Comment: You are using a regular expression as the first parameter to replace.

Comment: Correct @KentWeigel

Comment: Instead of writing: `v.replace(/\s/gm, "").split(":");` you should write `v.split(/:\s*/);` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible with regex, if you really need to do this with regex then you can use the \s+ expressions, (one or more whitespace characters).